How would I get an object's final resting position with linear drag and velocity?
I'm trying to make a system to see if a knockback would hit an object into an area in the scene. How would I calculate this in 2D?
I know there's \${v_f}^2 = v_i^2 + 2ad\$, but that only works with a constant deceleration.
EDIT: Tried this, but it never returned true
private bool WillLandInZone(Collider2D zone) {
        float brakeConstant = (1 - (1/Time.fixedDeltaTime)*GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().drag) * (float)Math.Exp((1 / Time.fixedDeltaTime));
        Vector2 finalPos = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position - (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity / (float)Math.Log(brakeConstant));
        return zone.bounds.Contains(finalPos);
}


Does this answer your question? Calculating framerate-independent values, for linear, quadratic, and exponential functions - see the formula $\vec p(t) = \vec p_0 + \frac {\vec v_0(b^t - 1)} {\ln b}$ which expresses the position at time t in terms of the initial position and velocity and the braking ratio $b$ (the fraction of the velocity that should remain after 1s). As $t$ approaches infinity, this approaches $\vec p(t) = \vec p_0 - \frac {\vec v_0} {\ln b}$.

Kind of? I'd need to find the breaking constant in unity first so I'll check it when I get home in a few hours

Unity's Box2D physics engine calculates linear damping using this formula $v_1 = v_0 \cdot \text{clamp}(1 - \Delta t \cdot d, 0, 1)$. At the default physics tick rate of 50 Hz, that means $b = (1 - \frac 1 {50} d)^{50}$, where $d$ is the drag parameter on your Rigidbody2D.

ohhhh okay I see, I'll try and check these and see if they work I'll keep the post updated. Also how'd you get the exponent in the equation

@LudoProf
So I tried implementing the equation but I'm getting inconsistent results and won't return true unless its inside the collider, check OP

You've mistranslated the formula into code. A correct formula would be float brakingRatio = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Clamp01(1f - Time.fixedDeltaTime*body.drag), 1f/Time.fixedDeltaTime); - note how we're only using the reciprocal of $\Delta t$ the second time, not the first. Multiplying $a \cdot e^x$ is not the same as raising a to the power of x.

ahhh right sorry didn't know how to do exponents in C# since I came from lua which uses ^ for raising powers

Thanks for @DMGregory and @LudoProf for the help! I used this function and it worked out perfectly for me:
private bool WillLandInZone(Collider2D zone)
{
    float brakeConstant = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Clamp01(1f - Time.fixedDeltaTime * GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().drag), 1f / Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    Vector2 finalPos = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position - (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity / (float)Math.Log(brakeConstant));
    return zone.bounds.Contains(finalPos);
}


LudoProf is the account I use when I'm not on my personal device, so it's just me.

Also, any reason you're using System.Math.Log(double) then casting down to a float, instead of using Mathf.Log(float)?

oh lamo- well thanks for the help regardless :D, also I gonna be honest I'm just so used to using System.Math I forgot Mathf was a thing sometimes

Here's a function that should do the job, assuming only "linear drag" is acting on the body (no gravity, collisions, friction, or other external forces):
static Vector2 PredictStopPoint(Rigidbody2D body) {
    var velocity = body.velocity;
    var speed = velocity.magnitude;

    // This is how much speed remains after one physics tick of drag.
    // Using Box2D's drag formula explained here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160055/39518
    var residual = Mathf.Clamp01(1f - Time.fixedDeltaTime * body.drag);

    // When the velocity drops below the linear sleep tolerance,
    // the physics engine stops the body. So we solve the equation:
    // speed*(residual^ticksToStop) <= linearSleepTolerance
    // to know how many physics ticks in the future that will be.
    var ticksToStop = Mathf.CeilToInt(
        Mathf.Log(Physics2D.linearSleepTolerance / speed)
        / Mathf.Log(residual)
    );

    // Using the formula for a finite geometric series,
    // we can compute how far we'll travel in that time,
    // measured in units of our initial displacement per physics step:
    float ticksWorth = (1f - Mathf.Pow(residual, ticksToStop))/(1f - residual);

    // Scaling this up by our pre-drag displacement per tick:
    return body.position + ticksWorth * velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
}

This differs from the approach discussed in the comments above in that it takes into account that the engine is only simulating this in finite time steps, up to a maximum number of iterations given by the linear sleep tolerance, rather than being a truly continuous function extending toward a limit at infinite time.
We get some accumulating floating point error in these calculations, and different accumulating error in the physics engine when it actually ticks the object, so the two results don't match perfectly. In my tests, the error is consistently smaller than 1% of a world unit or 0.1% of the distance travelled, across a wide range of initial speeds and drag parameter values.
The errors with the continuous model (shown in the other answer) are about 100x larger in my tests, but that can be a reasonable trade-off for simplicity if you only need approximate predictions.
